# Properly allocate an array with placement new

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocation, memory-alignment, placement-new

I'm building a memory allocator and making use of placement new. 
Say I want to "place" 10 elements to an already allocated array on the heap.

First regular new allocates the necessary amount of Bytes on the heap, then i construct my `WE` objects at appropriate locations.

```
struct WE {
    WE() {
        std::cout << "WE default constructed\n";
    }
    ~WE() {
        std::cout << "WE default destructed\n";
    }

    double d;
    int i;
    char c;
};
```

Is the following usage of placement new correct?

Code compiles and output seems correct, but I have some doubts.

```
// 1. allocate
const int elements = 10;
int nbytes = elements * sizeof(WE);
char* memory = new char[nbytes];
WE* pB = (WE*)memory;
int step = sizeof(WE);
// 2. construct
for (int i = 0; i < nbytes; i += step)
    new (pB + i) WE();
// 3. process
for (int i = 0; i < nbytes; i += step)
    pB[i].i = i * 2;
for (int i = 0; i < nbytes; i += step)
    std::cout << '[' << i << ']' << '=' << pB[i].i << '\n';
// 4. destruct
for (int i = 0; i < nbytes; i += step)
    pB[i].~WE();
// 5. deallocate
delete[] memory;
pB = nullptr;
memory = nullptr;
```

If all is well with question above, then allow me an addition question, how would I align this array on an arbitrary byte boundary?
Say I want alignment at a `sizeof(WE)` which is `16` (and not at `alignof(WE)` which is `8`). Would this modification: `alignas(sizeof(WE)) char* memory = new char[nbytes];` be enough to do the trick? I've also heard of `std::aligned_storage`. I'm not sure whether it could provide any benefits. (If the second question confused you, or if I've messed things up on part 1, forget about it.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: All your `for` loops are wrong, `pB + i` performs pointer arithmetic on a pointer of type `WE*`, not `char*`

Comment: @UnholySheep Well, that is what I want, I want to "place" `WE` objects not chars. Chars were only for the allocation part.

Comment: Yes, but you allocated an array of size `nbytes * sizeof(char)`, not `nbytes * sizeof(WE)` - you are iterating way past the bounds of it with your `for` loops

Comment: The for loops should be `i < elements; i++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For objects construction (placement new), you can either iterate byte/char-wise:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nbytes; i += step) new (memory + i) WE();
```

or element-wise:

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) new (pB + i) WE();
```

In the remaining loops, where you access the elements, you need to use the second option.

As for alignment, dynamic memory allocation returns a memory chunk aligned at `alignof(std::max_align_t)` (C++11). The exemplary value is 16 (GCC/x86_64), which is what you want, but this value is of course not guaranteed by the Standard.

If I am not wrong, before C++17 `operator new` cannot allocate memory for over-aligned objects directly and `std::aligned_storage` does not help here. From C++17, there are special versions of `operator new` that accept alignment information, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new.